# Change view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

how can I change ViewController to another VC?
Example:
I have LogVC and UserDetailVC.
When user write username and pass on logVC need change to userDetailVC.
-When user not login, he can't see userDetailVC
-And when user login,, he can't see logVC until go out
Now I made

```
let userController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userDetailVC") as! userDetailVC
self.present(userController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Window change to userDetailVC, but I haven't got a TabBarController

Comment: Are this two viewController in same story board or in different storyboard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in same a storyBoard then you can simply do this -
Take a button in your `LogVC` and `ctrl+ drag` a segue upto your `UserDetailVC`. Then click on the segue. (the round thing on between two view controller). -

[image]

And set a identifier for that (here `about` is the identifier, you can give any name for this)-

[image]

Here is the code -

```
@IBAction func UserDetailVC(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueIdentifierName", sender: sender)
    }
```

Or if you want to navigate to Controller on StoryBoard with Identifier "userDetailVC", then do this(this will applicable when you are trying to show one storyboard's `ViewController` to another storyboard `ViewController`):

```
   let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
   let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userDetailVC") as! userDetailVC
   self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a segue in your storyboard and call the `performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: self)`

If you have your view controllers in a a navigation controller, set the segue style as `push` otherwise set is as `modal`to present it on top of your current view controller